# Android Management API features

Tags: android, android-management-api

Two questions for [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management/introduction):

1. Does the API support custom policies, similar to [managed configurations](https://developer.android.com/work/managed-configurations#overview)?
2. Can applications report custom data back to the API?

Looking through the APIs, I see I can [send commands](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/issueCommand) to a device, and potentially [get application events](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices#applicationreport). Not sure these are best paths forward however.

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes, the  API does support managed configurations. You are required to create an [enterprise policy](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies/patch) first and then within that policy you can create an [ApplicationPolicy](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#applicationpolicy) where you may configure permissions and managed configurations. This can be done using either of the available **managedConfiguration** or **managedConfigurationTemplate** properties. In the case of using managedConfigurationTemplate, you'd have to provide the template id created using the [managed configurations iframe](https://developers.google.com/android/management/managed-configurations-iframe).

2) [ApplicationReport](http://ApplicationReport) reports pre-defined application data as seen on a particular device where it is installed. [Application](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.applications#Application) is a general application info resource where one can find about the app's permissions and managed properties available. Custom, app specific data reporting is not possible in the current (Jan, 2019) API version. Your app would have to implement its own mechanism to send such data to the EMM console, e.g., push notifications, etc.